# How to create json from array in php like APIs

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a sample 2018 student pass record of CSV file like this...

```
1 | Jonathan | 4CS-10 | 1,2,3,4 | Pass with credit
2 | Peter Jo | 4CS-11 | 1,2,3,4 | Pass with credit
```

and I want to convert it into Json. So firstly I thought I need to change it into php array and then i have to use json_encode function.

I have fetched CSV data into array with `fgetcsv()`.
The final json result I want to achieve is the following:

```
{"2018" : { 
  "4CS-10" : {
      "name" : "Jonathan",
      "destinations": "1,2,3,4"
    },
  "4CS-11" : {
      "name" : "Peter Joe",
      "destinations": "1,2,3,4"
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working as you expect it to?

Comment: You could use `explode` for turning a string into an array. Please see the documentations https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To produce that structure you need to iterate your CSV array and transform the rows to associative arrays, then add each row to your output array using the second column as a key.

```
foreach ($your_array as $row) {
    //      ↓ use 4CS-10, etc. as keys
    $data[$row[2]] = ['name' => $row[1], 'destinations' => $row[3]];
    //       convert numeric keys ↑ to string keys ↑   
}
echo json_encode(['2018' => $data]);
```

You may have trouble with this if the column you're using as key (values like `4CS-10`, etc.) is not unique. If any values there are repeated, you'll only get the last row from the CSV because you'll overwrite the original value of that key. If that's the case, you'll need to change your structure a little if you want to get all the data, and make the value under 4CS-10 an array of objects instead of a single object.

```
$data[$row[2]][] = ['name' => $row[1], 'destinations' => $row[3]];
```